# How to pass a line number variable to sed, to delete all lines after that line

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am having trouble passing this variable into sed in a bash script. I was able to successfully do the reverse of what I am asking (delete all lines prior to a specified line number) following this syntax.

```
    sed "1,${line_number}d"
```

but trying to recreate a similar answer to delete all lines after a line number continuously gives me errors. I have tried follwing:

```
    sed "${line_number},$d" #results in unexpected comma
    sed "|${line_number}|,|$d|" #trying to use a separator gives me an error for missing command
```

I'm not sure why the first would work but the second one would not. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

In `sed "${line_number},$d"` the second `$` is also interpret by bash. Bash sees `$d` and expands it, probably to the empty string if you didn't assign any value to `d`. You effectively execute something like `sed '5,'` which explains the `unexpected comma`.

To fix the problem, escape the second `$`:

```
sed "$line_number,\$d"
```

By the way, instead of deleting the lines starting at `$line_number` you can also extract the `$((line_number-1))` first lines which is probably faster:

```
head -n "$((line_number-1))"
```

Comment: Ah it was so easy! Thanks for the response this is just what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest always checking what real literal text you just coded in the string literal with simple `echo`:

```sh
line_number=3
echo "${line_number},$d"
# => 3,
```

This reveals the secret of the unexpected `,`.

Then, only double quote the variables, the rest of `sed` command is better quoted with single quotes:

```sh
sed "${line_number}"',$d' file > newfile
```

`"${line_number}"` is inside double quotes and thus the variable expansion will take place, the rest is inside single quotes, no variable expansion will thus occur.

See an online test:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
line_number=3
s='Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5'
echo "${line_number},$d"
sed "${line_number}"',$d' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```sh
3,
Line 1
Line 2
```